# Prove that there are infinitely many primes using $Q=p_{1}\cdot p_{2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{m}$ and $R=p_{m+1}\cdot p_{m+2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification

In an exercise I am supposed to prove the infinitude of the primes using the following:

Let $p_{1}, p_{2}, \cdots , p_{n}$ be the first $n$ primes and $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $1<m<n$. Let $Q$ be the product of all primes up to $m$. That is $$Q=p_{1}\cdot p_{2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{m}$$ and $R$ the product of the remaining primes in the list, meaning $$R=p_{m+1}\cdot p_{m+2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{n}.$$ Now, the exercise tells me to consider $Q+R$ and show that it is not divisible by any of the primes in the list $p_{1}, p_{2}, \cdots , p_{n}$ and hence must have a factor not included in the list. From this on may conclude that there are infinitely many primes (?). My attempt:

Consider $Q+R$. $$Q+R=(p_{1}\cdot p_{2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{m})+(p_{m+1}\cdot p_{m+2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{n}).$$ Now, suppose (by way of contradiction) that $\exists p_{k}$ in the list $p_{1}, p_{2}, \cdots , p_{n}$ such that $p_{k}\mid Q+R$. That is $$(p_{1}\cdot p_{2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{m})+(p_{m+1}\cdot p_{m+2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{n})=l\cdot p_{k}$$ for some $l\in \mathbb{Z}$. But this is impossible since all prime factors of $Q$ are different from the prime factors of $R$ which implies that either $p_{k}\mid Q$ or $p_{k}\mid R$, but not both. Thus $Q+R$ must be divisible by a prime number which does not appear in the list $p_{1}, p_{2}, \cdots , p_{n}$. Therefore there must be infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, and the classic proof (with no splitting of primes and just adding $1$) corresponds to the case where $R$ is the empty product, i.e. $1$.

Comment: OK. Thanks! For some reason I am still confused about how this proves the infinitude of primes. Is it because given any "size" of the list of primes $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots p_{n}$, $Q+R$ is always divisible by some prime factor which does not appear in that list? The more "classic" proof using $Q_{n}=p_{1}\cdot p_{2}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{n}+1$ is more intuitive, I think...

Comment: @VictorGaleano You add the new prime whose existence is proven by this argument to the list, then repeat the argument. You can't stop. So there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: Note that you start with "the first $n$ primes" and prove that the listing of primes is not complete. That is not to say, however, that any new primes identified by your scheme will be $p_{n+1},p_{n+2},p_{n+3}$ etc. So in the ensuing steps, your collection of primes may not start with the first $p_{n+k}$ primes; just more than $n$ primes.